# Closure scope issue: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object

Tags: php

I have an issue with the following code.

```
<?php

include_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

use Spatie\Async\Pool;

$pool = Pool::create();

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $task = new ExpensiveTask($i);
    $pool->add(function () use ($task) {
        return $task->delayedProcess();
    })->then(function ($output) {
        print "Completed task: " . $output;
    })->catch(function (Throwable $exception) {
        print $exception->getMessage();
    })->timeout(function () {
        print "timeout";
    });
}

$pool->wait();

class ExpensiveTask {

    private $taskId;

    public function __construct(int $index) 
   {
       $this->taskId = $index;
   }

   public function delayedProcess() {
       sleep(1);
       return $this->taskId;
   }
}
```

On executing the above code I'm getting the following 500 error. Not sure why it's happening.

```
PHP Fatal error:  {closure}(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "ExpensiveTask" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition in closure://function () use ($task) {
        return $task->delayedProcess();
    } on line 3
```

How I can fix this, I'm new to PHP closures. Even I tried to declare the class before using it but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the class in composer autoload and is working fine.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["src/ExpensiveTask.php"]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An `incomplete Object` in PHP normally is just a class that does not exist (yet). Mind the order in which you declare and instantiate an object of your class.

Move your class declaration above your executing code and you should be fine.

**Edit**

> Even I tried to declare the class before using it but getting the same error.

Still, above holds true. In 99,9% of all cases it's your declaration/ execution order.

**Edit 2**

From your answer: The autoloader files just loaded before your custom class, which was not added to the autoloaders class map. So the answer still holds true. The class did load too late.

Comment: I swear to god I did that, still getting the same error. Seems like this is something serious.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan See Edit.